# I want to order two signals to one input in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, spartan

I want to have two signals (overflow1 and set1) for one input(tick).

```
counter2 : counter
generic map (border => 5, width => 4)
port map (RST => RST,
       tick => overflow1 [...] set1, -- overflow1 and set1 are these signals  
   enable => SW0,
       x => count2,
   overflow => overflow2);
```

so i want to fill the gap there. i hope u can understand my Problem.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that tick is an input port, and overflow1 and set1 are std_logic, then in VHDL-2008 you can do `overflow1 or set1`.

In previous VHDL versions, like VHDL-2002 and before, you must make an internal temporary signal like `temp <= overflow1 or set1`, and use that to drive the port.

Comment: Ok so yeah u see my problem. I already tried the first way and this failed so i guess that i work with an old version. how do i make an internal temp signal?

Comment: After `architecture ... is`, define new signal and then inside `begin ... end` assign value.

Comment: it already tried to mak this signal:"signal temp : STD_LOGIC;" and then the assign value: "temp <= overflow1 or set1;" but this doesnt work..and then of course: "tick => temp,"

Comment: @Alex Heintz: Can you share a bit more of your code (and the actual error message you receive) so we may be able to help more. The answer from MortenZdk and Qiu should be ok.